# Mac Downloads Folder in dock doesn't show Icons

Tags: dock, icon

My Downloads folder in the dock looks like this:

[image]

If I click on it, there are also no icons.

[image]

I tried removing it from dock and adding it back, but it shows the same result.

My system info:
[image]

The system was freshly installed about a month ago.

Comment: Have you restarted?

Comment: @benwiggy, I just installed macOS Monterey 12.4 and now it seems to work. It restarted during the proces and now it works. "Did you try to turn it on and off again" was indeed the fix... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @benwiggy mentioned, a simple reboot worked...

Comment: A restart didn't fix it for me :-/

Comment: Do you have Universal controls enabled? Settings->Displays->bottom: Universal Controls; disable if you have multiple mac's at home